cmake has not found boost_graph library
The problem is that cmake don't find boost-graph library during building of the project. However, this library is installed on the system.
Hello everyone!
I've faced with such problem.
I've tried to build some project that depends on Boost and CLapack packages. (I've installed these packages earlier)
I've used this command:
$ cmake ../project_name/ -DCLAPACK_BASE_DIRECTORY=/home/vitalii/clapack-3.2.1-CMAKE -DCLAPACK_BUILD_DIRECTORY=/home/vitalii/clapack-3.2.1-CMAKE/BUILD


The output in terminal was:
— The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
— The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
— Detecting C compiler ABI info
— Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
— Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
— Detecting C compile features
— Detecting C compile features - done
— Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
— Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
— Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
— Detecting CXX compile features
— Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/boost_graph-config.cmake

  but it set boost_graph_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_graph" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.

  The following variants have been tried and rejected:

  * libboost_graph.so.1.74.0 (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)

  * libboost_graph.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)

— Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/vitalii/Vitalii/lab/phd/cpf/cpf_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

42-45 lines of CMakeLists.txt are:
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS graph program_options REQUIRED)

587-594 lines of /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake are:
  if(BOOST_ROOT AND NOT Boost_ROOT)
    # Honor BOOST_ROOT by setting Boost_ROOT with CMP0074 NEW behavior.
    cmake_policy(PUSH)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
    set(Boost_ROOT "${BOOST_ROOT}")
    set(_Boost_ROOT_FOR_CONFIG 1)
  endif()
  find_package(Boost QUIET NO_MODULE ${_boost_FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS})

238-262 lines of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake are:
# Find components

if("ALL" IN_LIST Boost_FIND_COMPONENTS)

  # Make sure "ALL" is the only requested component.
  list(LENGTH Boost_FIND_COMPONENTS __boost_find_components_count)
  if(NOT ${__boost_find_components_count} EQUAL 1)
    message(AUTHOR_WARNING "ALL cannot be combined with named components; the named components will be ignored.")
  endif()

  unset(__boost_find_components_count)

  set(Boost_ALL_TARGETS Boost::headers)

  boost_find_all_components()

else()

  foreach(__boost_comp IN LISTS Boost_FIND_COMPONENTS)

**    boost_find_component(${__boost_comp} ${Boost_FIND_REQUIRED_${__boost_comp}} 0)**

  endforeach()

endif()

This command has proved that boost_graph library exists in my system:
$ find / -name *libboost_graph* 2> /dev/null
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/envs/my-rdkit-env/lib/libboost_graph.so.1.84.0
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/envs/my-rdkit-env/lib/libboost_graph.so
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/envs/AmberTools23/lib/libboost_graph.so.1.82.0
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/envs/AmberTools23/lib/libboost_graph.so
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/envs/AmberTools23/lib/cmake/boost_graph-1.82.0/libboost_graph-variant-shared.cmake
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/libboost-devel-1.82.0-h00ab1b0_6/lib/cmake/boost_graph-1.82.0/libboost_graph-variant-shared.cmake
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/boost-cpp-1.78.0-h2c5509c_4/lib/libboost_graph.so
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/boost-cpp-1.78.0-h2c5509c_4/lib/libboost_graph.so.1.78.0
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/boost-cpp-1.78.0-h2c5509c_4/lib/cmake/boost_graph-1.78.0/libboost_graph-variant-shared.cmake
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/libboost-1.84.0-hba137d9_3/lib/libboost_graph.so.1.84.0
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/libboost-1.84.0-hba137d9_3/lib/libboost_graph.so
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/libboost-1.82.0-h6fcfa73_6/lib/libboost_graph.so.1.82.0
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/libboost-1.82.0-h6fcfa73_6/lib/libboost_graph.so
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/boost-cpp-1.78.0-h6582d0a_3/lib/libboost_graph.so
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/boost-cpp-1.78.0-h6582d0a_3/lib/libboost_graph.so.1.78.0
/home/vitalii/anaconda3/pkgs/boost-cpp-1.78.0-h6582d0a_3/lib/cmake/boost_graph-1.78.0/libboost_graph-variant-shared.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph.so.1.74.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph_parallel.so.1.74.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph_parallel.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph_parallel.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/libboost_graph-variant-static.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/libboost_graph-variant-shared.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph_parallel-1.74.0/libboost_graph_parallel-variant-static.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph_parallel-1.74.0/libboost_graph_parallel-variant-shared.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph.a


Also I've read some answers on the related questions.
I've tried run cmake with option -DBoost_DEBUG=TRUE to get more information as some users in these answers had recommended it:
$ cmake ../project_name/ -DCLAPACK_BASE_DIRECTORY=/home/vitalii/clapack-3.2.1-CMAKE -DCLAPACK_BUILD_DIRECTORY=/home/vitalii/clapack-3.2.1-CMAKE/BUILD -DBoost_DEBUG=TRUE
— Found Boost 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0
— Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph;program_options
— BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake)
— Found boost_headers 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_headers-1.74.0
— BoostConfig: find_package(boost_graph 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake)
— Found boost_graph 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0
— Boost toolset is gcc11 (GNU 11.4.0)
— Scanning /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/libboost_graph-variant*.cmake
— Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/libboost_graph-variant-shared.cmake
— [ ] libboost_graph.so.1.74.0
— Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/libboost_graph-variant-static.cmake
— [ ] libboost_graph.a
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
Found package configuration file:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/boost_graph-config.cmake

but it set boost_graph_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_graph" is
considered to be NOT FOUND. Reason given by package:

No suitable build variant has been found.

The following variants have been tried and rejected:

* libboost_graph.so.1.74.0 (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)

* libboost_graph.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594
22:55
(find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)

— Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/vitalii/Vitalii/lab/phd/cpf/cpf_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Unfortunately, I haven't yet understood how to fix this problem. Do you have any suggestions for it?
My OS is 22.04.1-Ubuntu.

What is not clear in the error message? The line * libboost_graph.so.1.74.0 (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON) means that your system have libboost_graph.so as shared library, but find_package is asked to find only static variant (you set Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS variable for that). The line * libboost_graph.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON) means that your system have libboost_graph.a library with dynamic runtime, but your request to find only Boost with the static runtime (Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON).

Note 99% of the library is header only.. chances are pretty good you don't need the link dependency anyways. Just depends on Boost::boost or Boost::headers - I always te forget which

@Tsyvarev, thank you very much!
The problem has been solved with your help)
